# Dynamically change the condition in if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, if-statement

This code is to dynamiclly change the condition , however, this statement is recognized and interperted by chrome but not fx , how to fix the problem ? thanks

```
if a % 2 == 0 
  var condition = b == c  || b == d;
else 
  var condition = b == e  || b == f ;

if (condition)
  ......
```

Comment: Any variable declared as `var someVar` will be hoisted to the top of the scope, so you only need to use the `var` keyword once per symbol.

Comment: This code should work fine in Firefox.  Can you link to a testcase that doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var condition = (a % 2 == 0) ? (b == c  || b == d) : (b == e  || b == f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this:

```
var condition;
if (a % 2 == 0)
    condition = b == c  || b == d;
else 
    condition = b == e  || b == f ;

if (condition)
   ......
```

Comment: Because you got condition definied before you use it.

Comment: What purpose will that serve? It's an `if-else` conditional, either the `if` or the `else` will execute, so the variable gets defined inside one of them anyway...

Comment: I can tell how it is in C#, C++ and Java, when you want to use a variable out of an if else statement you have to define it before you use it.

Comment: But not in Javasript. In JS, a variable declared with `var` will always be pre-initialized with `undefined`, so even if the conditional doesn't evaluate to `true` and the variable never gets the chance to be given the supposed value, because the code never *enters* that unit, outside that unit, it's value will be `undefined`...

Comment: But the variable is unknow outside the if else construct, isn't it?

Comment: No, it's `undefined`, but not `unknown`. Try out this code : `a = 3; if (a == 4) { var b = 5; } else { var b = 6; } console.log(b);`. It will show `undefined`, whereas you follow the code up by some other variable like `console.log(dfg)`, you will get an error. All variables with `var` are initialized the moment they are declared. This is a unique JS trait...

Comment: Ok, my mistake. The most time I program in C# and Java, where I retrieve a compilererror when I don't initalize a variable. So, my JS style is a little bit influenced by C# and Java programming conventions ^^

Comment: No problem, it happens to the best of us..:)

Comment: This actually isn't a bad answer, even though you didn't know _why_ it is or isn't the right answer.

Comment: Frankly I am surprised that this hasn't yet received a downvote. From my experience, most of the SO users are hyper-active as regards downvoting answers without discussing with the answerer, closing questions, etc...

Comment: Yes, me too, maybe because it is weekend and today is superbowl :) And when I don't calculate wrong it is in the US 8 o'clock ;)